# Autodesk Forge Viewer - Selecting large number of elements (performance)

Tags: performance, selection, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a large federated model loaded in Autodesk Forge Viewer (~300k elements from several IFC files). I'm doing a cross-model (aggregate) selection like this:

```
var selection = [{model1 : [ids...]}, {model2 : [ids...]}, {model3: [ids...]}, etc...);
viewer.impl.selector.setAggregateSelection(selection);
```

Now, given that the number of selected elements goes to 100k+, this freezes the UI for a couple of seconds, then once all of the elements get highlighted in the viewer the performance (fps) of the viewer degrades significantly. Switching to isolation instead of selection (highlighting) improves viewer performance but it still freezes the UI for a couple of seconds while doing it.

Are there any performance tips when doing these large selections, can the selection/isolation process be done async so the UI feels more responsive?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the selection mechanism (both the state toggling and the rendering) isn't optimized for such numbers, and there's no way to optimize it yourself. This would require a code update in the internal viewer implementation.

Before we pass this to the engineering team, however, I would like to ask about your actual use case. The selection functionality is typically used to bring user's attention to one (or a small number) of elements in the design, or to allow the user to choose one (or a small number) of elements for some further processing. But selecting 100k+ elements, and then continuing the use of the viewer with those 100k+ elements selected? What exactly do you need that for? Have you considered using other features of the viewer such as the [theming colors](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#setthemingcolor-dbid-color-model-recursive)?

Comment: Hi Petr, thanks for the answer. It isn't really much about selecting, the goal is to make a group of elements pop over other elements in order to make it more noticeable to the user. The use-cases can be many, e.g. select elements that have area > 10m2, elements which were constructed in a certain phase, elements with openings etc. Will theming be able to work efficiently with a larger number of elements?

Comment: Theming color is built into the standard material/shader so I believe it's definitely a better approach.

Comment: Great, will try it. Just one more thing, is there a possibility to da an aggregated theming for multiple elements on many models (like setAggregateSelection(selection))? In the API docs it appears that it only receives a single dbid and model as an argument.

Comment: The theming is actually provided on several levels: (1) via `viewer.setThemingColor` (specifying both the model and the object ID), (2) via `model.setThemingColor(dbid, color, recursive)`, or (3) via `fraglist.setThemingColor(dbid, color)` on the fragment list level (each model has a flat list of "fragments" representing individual geometries with their materials, xforms, etc.).

Comment: I don't think there's any higher level function, though. If you want to color something in a multi-model scenario, you need to tell us which model we're talking about.

Comment: I was thinking more in terms for it to accept a single array [ { model1, ids1 }, { model2, ids2], ... ] instead of foreaching and calling setThemingColor for each id in each model that we want to set colors to. Either way, I gave it a spin and it works like a charm, much faster than selecting or isolating. Thanks Petr!

Comment: Awesome, cheers! And regarding your comment on being able to pass in a single array of model/objectids, I'll pass that on to the viewer engineering team.

Comment: Any updates on this and being able to pass multiple models/ids in a single array?