# Autodesk Forge Viewer. Selecting large number of elements (updating question)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Following this discussion [Autodesk Forge Viewer - Selecting large number of elements (performance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64100445/autodesk-forge-viewer-selecting-large-number-of-elements-performance). Today is November 2022, maybe something has changed in the situation with the selection of a large number of elements? For example, in my case, I may need to select one million elements in the model (a model of a large building)

Comment: How did you manage to achieve good performance for 1M elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you're not using this feature yet, consider looking at the "selection type" that can now be passed to selection methods such as [toggleSelect](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#toggleselect-dbid-model-selectiontype). The selection type can be one of the following:

- `Autodesk.Viewing.SelectionType.OVERLAYED`

  - Nodes are tinted with the selection color and shown on top of the not selected geometry.
  - This does not scale for larger number of selected elements as they are rendered **twice** - once using their original shader, and then again using the highlight shader
- `Autodesk.Viewing.SelectionType.REGULAR`

  - Nodes are tinted with the selection color.
  - This is better for performance reason - selected objects are only rendered **once**, with a color tint applied to their shader
- `Autodesk.Viewing.SelectionType.MIXED`

  - Leaf nodes are selected using the overlayed selection type, and inner nodes are selected using regular selection type.